# Is taking photos from a video still photography?

Tags: gopro, philosophy

I want to take photos out from a video that I took, but would that still be photography?

Comment: Would it be photography according to whom? The photography police?

Comment: Vote to reopen. This isn't too broad. I was in the middle of typing an answer when it got closed.

Comment: What about "P" (spray and pray) photography?  It's worked for me to capture a good photo of a baby or animal that won't hold still for a pose.  Take a burst of 5 photos and throw away 4 (or often, all) of them.

Comment: @RyanFromGDSE It's been closed as "opinion based", not too broad. There is no "photography police" to define what is allowed, so any answers *must* be opinion based.

Comment: @PhilipKendall sorry wrong close reason but too late to edit. Your answer is inaccurate, or more precisely incomplete. If this gets reopened I could leave a proper answer.

Comment: So open a meta post and explain why it's not opinion based.

Comment: @PhilipKendall "There is no photography police to define what is and isn't considered a photograph" - that you can answer it says its not a matter of opinion. But I made a meta post for you: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5345/i-dont-think-this-is-opinion-based

Comment: Are you trying to ask if a question about this would be on-topic for this site? Or are you wondering about the boundries here _in general_?

Answer (score 6):

If the result is a photograph, then it's photography.

A video is just a sequence of still frames, and recording video is only 1 step up from the high speed drive modes (sports modes) on most cameras.

The characteristics of the image are often quite different:

- Defects which wouldn't be visible in a moving video may become quite noticeable in stills
- Resolution is quite a bit lower in video
- Different framing techniques are often used for moving subjects.

I think you can argue that video IS photography. Take a look at the credits of films, you often see a 'Director of Photography'

Comment: Also, there's a reason the term "*still* photography" exists....

Comment: @ths I dont' think so.  Unless you just Whooshed me, that is.   <badjoke> "Still photography" refers to photos of whiskey manufacturing machines </badjoke>

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: see wikipedia: "Still photography is the practice of making non-moving photographs, as distinct from motion picture photography (cinematography).

In the motion picture industry, a person making still photographs is known as the unit still photographer."

Answer (score 1):

In photography you can control the shutter speed (meaning the exposure time) at will (or at least allowing for available light).

In videography and cinematography [the exposure time is *normally* set to twice the frame rate](https://vimeo.com/blog/post/frame-rate-vs-shutter-speed-setting-the-record-str).  So if you're shooting 60fps, your exposure time is fixed st 1/120th sec.  This rule isn't set in stone, as that link discusses in more detail.

This is done so that motion blurring is reproduced in a way that let's the human cinema/video viewer correctly interpret it.

Now in photography you would (should) choose your shutter speed to match the effect you want.

So for some purposes a video frame won't work well as you (typically) let go of control of shutter speed.

I would say it is, in broad terms, a kind of photography.  It's a way of getting a still image while using the camera for video.  It's a matter of priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Some would consider it cheating since a good deal of the skill of photography is in setting up the shot, which includes timing. The bigger issue will be the quality of the result - video captures don't have the quality that most people expect from still photography. A 1080p video only produces 2 megapixels! A 4k video will hit 8 megapixels, which was acceptable 10 years ago but is cell-phone quality today. In addition the compression applied to videos is more severe than the compression applied to photographs, with the theory being that you won't notice fleeting artifacts. Those artifacts will be permanently baked into the image once you take a single frame.

Those are the reasons why it isn't commonly done, but it's not the last word. If you have a video and you've taken a frame from it that makes *you* happy, then you have a legitimate photo.

Comment: This really isn't relevant.  Resolution has nothing to do with a photo being a photo.  And further, everyone here seems to forget that it's possible even in 2017 to shoot movies with 35mm (or 70mm) emulsion film.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you have a good point. But there are reasons people don't do this more often.